# Product image size issue - Fotorama - Magento EE 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-images, fotorama

I have issue in image height calculation in fotorama in Magento EE 2.2.4.
The image div(fotorama__stage)height is assigning by Script as inline css.

It is happens in some products only.

```
<div class="fotorama__stage" data-fotorama-stage="fotorama__stage" style="width: XXXpx; height: XXXpx;">
```

This is the perfect height assigned to the div as per image size.
[image]

This is the imperfect height assigned to the div as per image size.
[image]

Sometimes it displays perfect image as per actual image size but sometimes it displaying incorrectly.

I'm using Magento EE 2.2.4 with production mode.
I have only configurable products in this project.

Anyone know about such kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

***add "maxheight": "550", // Add your value here***

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                "breakpoints": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>,
                "maxheight": "550"  //Add your value here
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is not working...
I want to change height of `<div class="fotorama__stage"></div>` which is assigned from `fotorama.js` .